# Rcpp Error Null value passed as symbol address

Tags: r, rcpp

I am  new to Rcpp.

I created an rcpp function which takes a dataframe with 2 columns and a vector as input, and returns a vector. 
My data are as below

```
set.seed(10)
min= sort(rnorm(1000,800,sd=0.1))
max= min+0.02
k=data.frame(min,max)
explist= sort(rnorm(100,800,sd=0.2))
```

Then I call the cfilter.cpp

```
k$output <- cfilter(k,explist)

#include <Rcpp.h> 
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector cfilter(DataFrame k, NumericVector explist) {

  NumericVector col1 = k["min"];
  NumericVector col2 = k["max"];
  NumericVector exp = explist ;

  int n = col1.size();
  int j = 0;
  CharacterVector out(n);

  for (int i=0; i<n ; i++){
    out[i]=NA_STRING;

    while(exp[j]<= col2[i]){

        if( exp[j]>= col1[i] && exp[j]<= col2[i] ){
          out[i]="Y";
          break;
        }
        else if(exp[j]>col2[i]){

          break;
        }
        else {
          j++ ;
        }
    }

  }
 return out;
}
```

It run perfectly fine for 16171 times I called it. And then suddenly, in the loop 16172 it just stops with an error:

```
> myfile$output<- cfilter(k,explist2)
Error in .Call(<pointer: (nil)>, k, explist) : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
```

I checked k and explist for NA values but there aren't any, there is no problem whatsoever with the input.
I have no clue how to fix this and what causes this error.

Thanks in advance for any response

Comment: Please [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about creating a minimal yet reproducible example so that we can actually help you.  As it stands, we can't as we have _no idea_ about your data.

Comment: The example you provide runs without any error on my computer.

Comment: The loop you are referring to is in R, right? Please add that to make the example complete. BTW, what is the problem you are trying to solve? The unchecked increase of `j` looks odd to me.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I run the code on a remote server. It indeed runs without errors on my computer as well. I ended up restarting Rstudio and the error was fixed. However after several thousands loops it stops again, with no reason.

Comment: @RalfStubner this function checks if the values of explist are found in the ranges(min,max) of K. If there are rows (ranges) in k  that do not correspond in any value of the explist, I mark them as "NA" and then remove them in my R script.
I first subset my explist so that all the values are equal or greater than the minimum value of k[min].
Then, by sorting ascending both k and explist, I check if a given explist value appears in k only until it reaches a row in which k[max] is greater than this explist value. If it was not found, no need to look in the next rows of k.  Hope it makes sense

Comment: I think your `while` loop will not terminate if `max(explist) < max(k["min"])`, which might lead to errors like this. But without the actual code that produces the error (including the R-side sub-setting and looping) it is difficult to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem. I'm not an Rcpp expert, nor C++ nor, a backend coding expert.
I have circumvented this problem by re-sourcing my cpp file every time I want to make a call of the function. So, for example if following is your for loop:

```
for(i in 1:SampleSize){
   out[[I]]<-cfilter(k,explist)
 }
```

Do something like:

```
for(i in 1:SampleSize){
   sourceCpp("cfilter.cpp")
   out[[i]]<-cfilter(k,explist)
}
```

Again, I don't know exactly why this worked for me, but it worked. Based on my shallow knowledge of C++, it might be related to memory allocation and that every time you source, memory is released and hence there is no mis-allocation. But I think this is a very wild guess.
Best